# proof-explanation slutsky (multivariate version: vector)

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-explanation

I do not understand the proof of following Theorem (Slutsky)

Let $X_{n},Y_{n}$ be sequences of vector random elements. If $X_{n}$ converges in distribution to a random element $X$ and $Y_{n}$ converges in probability to 0, then

$$X_{n}+Y_{n}\ \overset{d}{\rightarrow} X$$

*proof*.
Let $ A \in \mathcal{B}^s$, $\mathbb{P}(X \in \partial A) = 0, \epsilon > 0$ and $A^\epsilon = "\epsilon ~ neighborhood ~  of A"$. f: $\epsilon \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(x \in A^\epsilon) $ is growing and only has countable many discontinuities. Let $f$ be continuous in $ \epsilon $ then $ \mathbb{P}(X \in \partial A^\epsilon) = 0 $.

That is the point I don't understand: Why $\mathbb{P}(X \in \partial A^\epsilon) = 0 $?

Comment: What does "Is $\epsilon$ steadiness point" mean?

Comment: I just edited my question.

Comment: I think the unwritten part is "let $ \epsilon\in\mathbb R_+$ be arbitrary." Then one can choose an $\epsilon$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X \in \partial A^\epsilon) = 0$